# Script B slows down script A

Tags: python, time, process, raspberry-pi

I am working with Python 2.7 on a Raspberry Pi.

I run a script A which is a for-loop, taking pictures every 30 seconds. Normally, for each iteration, it takes about 5 seconds to capture the scene and save it, and then it sleeps (for about 25 seconds) until the next iteration.

After some time I run a script B which is calculating stuff based on the images taken by script A. So the two scripts are running at the same time. I am not using subprocess or anything, just executing the two scripts separately.

My problem is : when script B is running, script A is slowed down a lot, so that sometimes the first 5 seconds turn into 25-30 seconds and then one iteration can last 40 seconds or more !

Do you know why durations are not respected in script A, and how I can solve this issue ?

Thanks :) !

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are in a Linux environment you can use nice command in order to balance the cpu usage.for example :

```
nice --12 script.py
```

the number above represents the amount of being nice to cpu.it is between -20 and +19.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the calculation amount of "script B" is nearly always the same you could subtract this time in seconds from the sleep timer.

2.You also could take the runtime in seconds of the scripts, that you will output at the end of their execution. The problem is the python programm will wait for a finished script before continuing.

```
import subprocess
import time
counter = 0
script_a_runtime = 0
script_b_runtime = 0

while True:
    counter += 1
    script_a = 0
    script_b = 0
    script_a_runtime = int(subprocess.check_output(['scripta']))
    if counter >=5:
        counter = 0
        script_b_runtime = int(subprocess.check_output(['scriptb']))
    sleeptime = 30 - script_a_runtime - script_b_runtime
    if sleeptime:
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

3.Timers

```
import datetime
import time
import subprocess
script_a_runtime = 0
script_b_runtime = 0

while True:
    counter += 1
    start_a = datetime.datetime.now()
    subprocess.check_output(['script_a'])
    finish_a = datetime.datetime.now()
    script_a_runtime = finish_a - start_a
    if counter >= 5:
        counter = 0
        start_b = datetime.datetime.now()
        subprocess.check_output(['script_b'])
        finish_b = datetime.datetime.now()
        script_b_runtime = finish_b - start_b
        sleeptime = 30 - script_a_runtime.seconds - script_b_runtime.seconds
    if sleeptime:
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

I dont think its a good idea to run those scripts that depend on each other side by side. Also if scriptA/B is not finished before it should be run again there may arise problems.